# Sending mail in Django 1.5 with Gmail smtp

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, gmail

I try to send mail with Gmail smtp in my Django App.
I followed some instructions to configure my setting.py file.

Here is my code snippet in setting.py file.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myusername@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

then I tried these commands below to send mail to my own gmail account:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
>>> email = EmailMessage('Mail Test', 'This is a test', to=['myusername@gmail.com'])
>>> email.send()
```

it returned 1 to me, it should be successful. 
However, I can't find the testing mail in my inbox in my gmail.
Are there anything which I missed to set?
I run my Django site on localhost in Debug mode. And the Django's version is 1.5.

Thanks in advance! Any suggestion is appreciated.

UPDTED:

I changed the following code

`EMAIL_BACKEND = django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend`

to

`EMAIL_BACKEND = django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`

And, I have succeed to send the mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You email backend is set to `dummy`. Change it to `smtp`

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#smtp-backend)

[Dummy backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#dummy-backend) just prints to the console, and does nothing

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just found the mistakes minutes ago :p Learned something new :) thanks.